# Keep stdout on screen AND in File

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, stdout

I open a command prompt window in XP.  There I run a command line program (foo.exe) and I want to capture stdout in a file.  So I run it like this:

foo > fooResult.txt

However, at the same time I would like stdout to still be fed to the screen of the command prompt window.  What is the syntax for that?

Answer (score 3):

`foo |`[`tee`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)`fooResult.txt`

Comment: Does this work out of the box in windows?

Comment: You need the `tee` executable, which is available at the link given.

Comment: Or on a new console, if he has Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Linux you could use `tee`, like this:

```
foo | tee fooResult.txt
```

This would do what you want.  Unfortunately (in this sense only, lest I upset somebody), you're using Windows.  Fortunately, there is a windows version of `tee` [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).